# Showing that the set $K^t=\{x\in X:d(x, K) < t\}$ is connected if $K\subset X$ is compact and connected in a normed space $(X,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a normed space with $d$ being the metric induced by the norm of the space. Suppose that $K\subset X$ is compact and connected. I am trying to show that then the set $K^t=\{x\in X:d(x, K) < t\}$ is also connected, but I can't seem to get all the details I want or need.

We know that open balls are convex and hence connected in a normed space and that $K^t = \bigcup_{x\in K}B(x, t)$. I wanted to say something like that since there cannot be such an $x\in K$ that for all $x\neq y\in K:B(x, t)\cap B(y, t) = \varnothing$, I could glue the set $K^t$ from the individual balls. Namely, since for any $x, y\in K:B(x, t)\cap B(y, t)\neq\varnothing$ the set $U = B(x, t)\cup B(y, t)$ is connected I wanted to glue $K^t$ as follows:

Fix any $x\in K$ and define $\mathcal{C}_x=\{B(y, t): y\in K, B(y, t)\cap B(x, t)\neq\varnothing\}$. Then $U:=\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal{C}_x}B$ is a connected set. But now I would need to continue this process with uncountably many times, gathering any balls touching $U$ and combining them into a connected set and I honestly don't see how that could work in my favor.

Comment: @geetha290krm I don't think so. I am a bit absent-minded for sure, so typos are a possibility. I wanted to ask about just about connectedness of this slightly extended set. Having said that, I have confidence that my question has been about regular connectedness since there is a result stating that union of two non-disjoint connected sets is still a connected set. This motivated my initial attempt of forming some suitable collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach might be showing that every element of $K^t$ is in the same connected component.

Consider an arbitrary point of $K^t$ and show that it must be in the same connected component of the points in $K$ (which are themselves in the same component because $K$ is connected).

Basically, it is sufficient to show that each of them is "connected to $K$". A sketch might look as follows:

$~$

Let $S$ be the connected component (in the space $K^t$) of a point $x_0\in K$.

Since for any ball $B_x=B(x,t)$ with $x\in K$ we know that $K\cup B_x$ is connected and contains $x_0$, it follows that $K\cup B_x\subset S$ for all $x\in K$.

Since every point of $K^t$ is in some $B_x$, we have $S=K^t$, so $K^t$ is connected.